# How Can I Install "QGIS Server" in a Windows 7 PC?

Tags: windows, qgis-server

I am trying to install the new "QGIS Server" feature that comes with QGIS 1.6 on my Windows PC.  The directions for this at the QGIS website only show instructions for Mac OS, and those in other GIS blogs show instructions for installing the feature on Linux machines.

I'm wondering if instructions for installation on Windows are available anywhere, or whether anybody can provide me with the steps for installing the feature on the Apache web server on my PC.

Comment: From the looks of the QGIS list, it isn't working out of the box yet with OSGeo4W, and they're looking for someone to help with the issue: http://www.mail-archive.com/qgis-user@lists.osgeo.org/msg08618.html

Comment: Dear Howard, I'm facing the same problem on a windows XP PC (QGIS 1.6 and Wampserver). Do you succeed to use QGIS mapserver with windows ? Renaud B.

Answer (score 4):

From: http://karlinapp.ethz.ch/qgis_wms/configuration/

> You need to have a webserver installed
> (e.g. Apache) and place the files for
> the QGIS mapserver in the FastCGI or
> CGI directory of your webserver. On
> Windows, QGIS mapserver currently can
> only be used as a CGI application. You
> also need to make sure the webserver
> finds libqgis_core.so/dll and
> libqgis_gui.so/dll and the Qt
> libraries when starting the server
> application.

For Apache this can achieved by extending the LD_LIBRARY_PATH in the webserver configuration file:

> **CGI:** Enter the following line into
> apache2.conf: SetEnv LD_LIBRARY_PATH Path_to_Qt_libraries:Path_to_QGIS_libraries
>
> **FastCGI:** Enter the following
> line into fcgid.conf: DefaultInitEnv LD_LIBRARY_PATH Path_to_Qt_libraries:Path_to_QGIS libraries

Comment: Thank you, relima!  I'd seen the reference you cited, but had dismissed it because it did not match the files I found in my two instances of Apache server in my PC.

Comment: Thank you, relima! There is no "apache2.conf" file in my "C:\OSGeo4W\apache\conf" folder.  There is, however, a "http.conf" file.  I may try to add the "SetEnv" path command in there.  Also, the only Qt *.dll files I can find are in "C:\OSGeo4W\bin" folder, so I guess I'll specify that as the "Path_to_Qt_libraries."  The qgis libraries seem to be in the "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\qgis\lib" folder, so I'll specify that path and see what happens.  I will report here on how it went.  If you have any further information, please let me know!  Thank you!

Comment: Howard, did you get this working in the end? I would be interesting to hear your report back as to whether this worked or not.

Comment: I apologize to everybody for the tardy reply.  I have not been able to make it work as of yet!